# node-sass Option

Tags: node.js, node-sass

**Gulp-sass** компилирует `sass` файлы при помощи **node-sass**, у котрого есть объект с различными опциями.

```
sass( {
        outputStyle: 'expanded',   // стиль вывода
        sourceComments: true,      // добавляет комментарий перед селектором в выходном файле о строке где этот селектор в исходном файле.
        indentType: 'tab',         // тип оступа
        indentWidth: 1,            // величина отступа  max-10
        includePaths: ['dev/scss/base/', 'dev/scss/elements/'] // массив путей подключаемых файлов, вроде как должно решать проблему импортов...

    })
```

так вот, есть там объект **functions** и в [документации](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#functions--v300---experimental) о нем написано совсем немного:

> Это экспериментальная функция LibSass. Используйте с осторожностью.
>
> функции является объект, который содержит набор пользовательских
>   функций, которые могут быть вызваны с помощью Sass файлов
>   составляются. Они могут принимать ноль или более входных параметров и
>   должны возвращать значение либо синхронно  `(return ...;)` или
>   асинхронно `(done();)`. Эти параметры будут экземплярами одного из
>   конструкторов, содержащихся в `require('node-sass').types`
>   хэшей. Возвращаемое значение должно быть одноним из этих типов. Смотрите
>   список доступных типов ниже: ......

более подробной документации я не нашел, и не совсем понятно для каких целей это можно использовать.
Так же очень интересен аргумент опций `importer`, насколько я понял он используется для определения пользовательской функции импорта подключаемых файлов. Хочется подробностей.
Знающие люди поделитесь информацией, желательно с примерами :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот Вам немного не-машинного перевода:

functions - это объект, который содержит набор пользовательских функций, которые могут быть вызваны во время компиляции. Они могут иметь произвольное количество входных параметров, и возвращать результат как синхронно (return), так и асинхронно (done). В качестве входных параметров вы получите инстансы типов (написано конструкторов, т.к. это js), содержащихся в хеше require('node-sass').types. Возвращаемое значение также должно быть инстансом одного из этих типов.

Далее в документе по вашей ссылке следует перечень типов, которые вы можете использовать в качестве входных параметров/возвращаемого значения таких функций, и далее - пример их использования, в котором Вы можете увидеть, как написать такую функцию, и как использовать ее внутри Sass:

```
sass.renderSync({
  data: '#{headings(2,5)} { color: #08c; }',
  functions: {
    'headings($from: 0, $to: 6)': function(from, to) {
      var i, f = from.getValue(), t = to.getValue(),
      list = new sass.types.List(t - f + 1);

      for (i = f; i <= t; i++) {
        list.setValue(i - f, new sass.types.String('h' + i));
      }

      return list;
    }
  }
});
```

В этом примере используется javascript-функция headings, которая принимает два параметра типа sass.types.Number, и возвращает список (sass.types.List) строк (sass.types.String) - тегов hX, где X, в данном примере - число от 2 до 5.

Это нужно, чтобы вы могли написать свою функцию на js, и использовать ее из Sass. Удобно. Только лучше не забывать, что функциональность это экспериментальная.

UPD:

А импортер нужен для ручного разрешения импортов, это там тоже подробно описано.
Эта функция (или несколько функций), которая принимает путь, который нужно разрезолвать, предыдущий разрезолваный путь и коллбэк, который нужно вызвать с Вашим результатом.

Результат - объект с полем "file", в котором лежит путь к нужному файлу, либо с полем "contents", в котором лежит уже содержимое файла, а не путь к нему.